# Issue using atoi in terms of stack, has number 318 instead of 3 saved

Tags: c++, linked-list, stack

I'm using stack and postfixParser. Instead of saving 3 it decides to go back and save the previous number too but I don't see why it would do that. Here's my code:

```
int postfixParser(string a)
{
  cout<<a<<endl;
  LinkedStack<int> Tempstack;
  int mult;
  for(int i=0; i<a.length();i++)
  {
    if(isdigit(a[i])&&isdigit(a[i+1])&&isdigit(a[i+2])&&isdigit(a[i+3]))
    {
      char chr[4];
      chr[0]=a[i];
      chr[1]=a[i+1];
      chr[2]=a[i+2];
      chr[3]=a[i+3];
      mult=0;
      mult=atoi(chr);
            cout<<"mult inside 4 digit"<<mult<<endl;
      Tempstack.push(mult);
      i=i+3;
    }
    else if(isdigit(a[i])&&isdigit(a[i+1])&&isdigit(a[i+2]))
    {
         char chr[3];
         chr[0]=a[i];
       chr[1]=a[i+1];
       chr[2]=a[i+2];
              mult=0;
      mult=atoi(chr);
      cout<<"mult inside 3 digit"<<mult<<endl;

      Tempstack.push(mult);
      i=i+2;
    }
    else if(isdigit(a[i])&&isdigit(a[i+1]))
    {
      char chr[2];
      chr[0]=a[i];
      chr[1]=a[i+1];
      mult=atoi(chr);
      cout<<"mult inside 2 digit"<<mult<<endl;

      Tempstack.push(mult);
      ++i;
    }
    else if(isdigit(a[i])) {//if it is a 1digit number
      char chr[1];
      chr[0]=a[i];
      mult=atoi(chr);
      cout<<"mult inside 1 digit"<<mult<<endl;
      Tempstack.push(mult);

    //     switch(a[i]){
    //     case '1':
    // Tempstack.push(1);
    //     break;
    //     case '2':
    // Tempstack.push(2);
    //     break;
    //     case '3':
    // Tempstack.push(3);
    //     break;
    //     case '4':
    // Tempstack.push(4);
    //     break;
    //     case '5':
    // Tempstack.push(5);
    //     break;
    //     case '6':
    // Tempstack.push(6);
    //     break;
    //     case '7':
    // Tempstack.push(7);
    //     break;
    //     case '8':
    // Tempstack.push(8);
    //     break;
    //     case '9':
    // Tempstack.push(9);
    //     break;
    //     case '0':
    // Tempstack.push(0);
    //     break;
    //   }
    }
    else if(a[i]==' ')
    {

    }
    else
    {
      int c=Tempstack.top();
      Tempstack.pop();
      int b=Tempstack.top();
      Tempstack.pop();
      switch(a[i])
      {
        case '+':
        Tempstack.push(b+c);
        break;
        case '-':
        Tempstack.push(b-c);
        break;
        case '*':
        Tempstack.push(b*c);
        break;
        case '/':
        if(c==0) { Tempstack.push(0);}
        else {Tempstack.push(b/c);}
      }
    }
  }

  return Tempstack.top();
}
```

When I try printing "18 3 4 * -" it has 18,  My code doesn't have it go back so why is my code going back. The issue is that if it went back to 18, wouldn't it print out "mult inside 2 digits"? It works with a switch statement(which is why I commented that out).

Comment: Where is your null terminator for your C style string?

Comment: You are `atoi` on a non terminated char. That you  'chr[0]=val' and chr[1] could be anything, you have undefined behavior. What @Avi Berger says.

Comment: @AviBerger what's a null terminator, is that where I set my chr to null?? sorry I'm new to atoi but I looked at the code on this page and they didn't set it to null: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/atoi/ How would you create a null terminator

Comment: @AbbasZaidi: On the page you linked to, the function `fgets` writes a null-terminated string to `buffer`. All functions that write C-style strings implicitly also write the terminating null character. See [this tutorial on C-style strings](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/ntcs/) for more information on how C-style strings are represented in memory.